# How to make an XMLHttpRequest that loads an HTML file into the div?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, request, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make an `XMLHttpRequest` that loads HTML from an external file and inserts the content of the file into the `div`.

When I run the function, it inserts the HTML in all of the body which is not adequate.

My code:

--------------------------> **HTML** <--------------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="shit.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" name="button" onclick="send()">Click me</button>
    <div class="view" id="view"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

--------------------------> **CSS** <--------------------------

```css
.view {
    margin-top: 5vh;
    height: 15vh;
    width: 80vw;
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
}
```

--------------------------> **JS** <--------------------------

```js
function send() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            document.write(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    var params = "type=search" + "&content=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("view").innerHTML);

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/include/link1.html", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById("view").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;` ?

Comment: nop, I´ll  try with that

Comment: I just updated the code with that part but It keeps doing the same as before mmm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
 var request;

 function sendInfo() {

  var url = "NewFile1.html";

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
   request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  try {
   request.onreadystatechange = getInfo;
   request.open("GET", url, true);
   request.send();
  }
  catch (e) {
   alert("Unable to connect to server");
  }
 }

 function getInfo() {
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
   var val = request.responseText;
   document.getElementById('chiru').innerHTML = val;
  }
 }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<marquee><h1>This is an example of ajax</h1></marquee>

<form name="vinform">
 <input type="button" value="ShowTable" onClick="sendInfo()">
</form>

<span id="chiru"> </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: put some html content in newfile1.html and check this code

Comment: I am needing to similar to the above.  The difference I have though is that my external HTML file is one big file broken into many sections.  Is there a way to only grab one section of the HTML file to be returned?  My big file is a helpPage.html and now I want to extract specific help sections to be pulled into other areas of my website.  `Dashboard` page, when user clicks the `?` icon, to extract the helpPage.html#dashboard section to be displayed into a modal.  I have everything else working, except how to extract the specific section.