# Import html from a cdn?

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer, cdn

This may be a stupid question, but I am doing a proof of concept for a feature which would be used in a polymer component (later be migrated to [Lit](https://lit.dev/)).

So, the use case is quite a simple one. As the older version of polymer support style modules instead of importing a stylesheet like we usually do in other libraries/frameworks. I want to load a few style modules from a cdn (or perhaps a much better way if we have).

Is that even an option?

Something like below:

```
import 'https://cdn.somedomain.com/style-module/custom-style-module.html';

...

<dom-module>
  <template>
    <style include="custom-style-module"><style>
  <template>
</dom-module>
```

This might sound vague as the concept of polymer doesn't exist anymore. But, if someone still working on something like this, please put your thoughts here.

Comment: It's not quite as clean as an `import` but it's possible to make an XHR request for an html file and drop that into the DOM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476100/how-to-make-an-xmlhttprequest-that-loads-an-html-file-into-the-div

Comment: Yes, might be an option, thanks.